# document() function and filenames that contain %

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm struggling with an XSL that processes a list of files. For most files, the function works correctly, but it breaks down when the filename contains a % sign.

This is my XSLT:

```
   <xsl:template match="file">
     <xsl:variable name="sourcedoc" select="concat('file:///', text())"/>
     <madcapfile>
        <xsl:attribute name="filename"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document($sourcedoc)"/>
     </madcapfile>
   </xsl:template>
```

and my XML with a list of files:

```
<file>the 7% solution.xml</file>
```

When processing this in Saxon, it complains that it can't find file 
"the 7olution.xml"

The XLST specifies this as the output:

```
<xsl:output method="xml"  escape-uri-attributes="no" />
```

Thanks to escape-uri-attributes="no", the URIs appear correctly in the transformed XML. I haven't been able to find an equivalent function that works on document(). 
How can I make sure document() treats % as a literal instead of converting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<xsl:variable name="sourcedoc" select="concat('file:///', encode-for-uri(.))"/>`, functions like `doc` or `document` work with URIs and the percent sign needs to escaped so if you have a file name with a percent sign the suggested function will escape it as needed so that the `doc` or `document` function will work.

Comment: To add to this: The argument to `document()` is not a file name, it is a URI. More strictly, it is a sequence of tokens each of which is interpreted as either an absolute URI or a relative URI reference; your string is neither, because of the %-sign.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this again, and thinking that if your input contains filenames rather than URIs, especially if the filenames come in arbitrary flavours, the best way of dealing with them might be to use the EXPath file module. That is:

```
parse-xml(file:read-text($filename))
```

or perhaps

```
doc(file:path-to-uri($filename))
```

The logic to convert a filename to a URI in the general case is quite complex, certainly more complex than sticking `file:///` at the front, and the EXPath file module attempts to tackle this problem, which the standard function library doesn't.